# Is "whom" correctly used in these two examples?

Tags: whom

N.B.: these are captions–intentional sentence fragments–for photographs.

1. Jason and Tonya, whom the Londoners loved.
2. The two sisters from New York City whom the the Hardings have adopted.

Edit: I was asked to update the question with at least fake names to make it easier to understand.

Comment: *Whom* is used for people, not things. Try *which* instead.

Comment: Apologies. I meant to add "a person" to the first two proper nouns in 1.

Comment: Please, please edit this to use real names for things, even made-up ones, instead of placeholders in brackets. It's too hard to understand what you mean otherwise.

Comment: Just updated the question. Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. In 1, [Proper noun, a person] and [proper noun, a person] are the objects of the sentence who are loved. In 2, [Plural proper noun, a certain group of people] from [proper noun, a place] are the objects of the sentence who have been adopted.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I agree with "yes", but in both examples "whom" is the direct object of the verb ("loved" and "adopted") in the relative clause introduced by "whom", not in "the sentence" (because the examples aren't sentences).  More generally, the case of a relative pronoun is determined  by its role in its own relative clause, not in the surrounding sentence.